# Closed Captions in YouTube API v3

Tags: java, youtube-api, google-api, closed-captions

I need to read closed caption text from *3rd party, publicly available YouTube videos* in my java webapp i.e. I have NOT uploaded the content.

Whilst [v2 of the YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_captions?hl=en) *restricted access to the caption information to the person who uploaded the video* it seems like a very odd restriction to give access to everything except this one piece of data. I expected to see this restriction removed in [v3 of the API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) but now the only reference to closed caption is a boolean method to confirm if CC is attached to the video. Even the owner can't seem to download it now. (Are Google going to add it back at least?)

```
Boolean hasCaptions = video.getContentDetails().getCaption()
```

Using YouTube Data API v3 (using the [Google Java API client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#YouTube_Data_API)) I have been able to find, authenticate and retrieve YouTube resources (videos, playlists, channels, etc.). I can do pretty much everything the API has made available I just can't read the actual caption text.

I've also tried the [unpublished timed text link workaround](http://googlesystem.blogspot.ie/2010/10/download-youtube-captions.html) but this is inconsistent, doesn't work for newer content and has many encoding errors in the content it does cover.

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a method for retrieving caption text from a YouTube video from java (not a .js plugin)?

[ Worst case, does anyone know of a library that allows me to programmatically interact with YouTube like a browser and *allows me to click the transcript button* on the screen and I can pull the transcript from there? [Prowser](http://prowser.sourceforge.net/) doesn't allow click interaction and [JxBrowser](http://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser/) is $1,300+ ]

The code below works fine and gets me to all the video data so it's the last step I need help on. I've included it here in case it's helpful to anyone who needs to get this far.

```
// Build a YouTube resource
YouTube youtube = new YouTube.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(),
                            new JacksonFactory(), 
                            new HttpRequestInitializer())
                    .setApplicationName("caption-retrieval")
                    .build();

// Create the video list request, it should only return one
// result
YouTube.Videos.List listVideosRequest = youtube.videos().list("id, snippet, contentDetails");
listVideosRequest.setKey(API_KEY));
listVideosRequest.setId(VIDEO_ID);

// Request is executed and video list response is returned
VideoListResponse listVideosResponse = listVideosRequest.execute();

List<Video> videos = listVideosResponse.getItems();

// Since a unique video id is given, it will only return
// one video. Would check if video has been removed in 
// production code.
Video video = videos.get(0);

// Read the remaining meta information
title = video.getSnippet().getTitle().trim();
author = video.getSnippet().getChannelTitle();

captionText = ???????
```

Any help is gratefully received.

Thanks,

Greg.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We are hoping to have Captions support on Data API v3 soon. You won't need to scrape the website.

Update: This has been implemented now. [The docs can be found here.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions)

Comment: Thanks @IbrahimUlukaya. That's great news. Do you have any sense on how soon that might be? Weeks, months, etc?

Comment: Soon?  Api v2 is going away in a year, and we would like to keep uploading captions.

Comment: Please, what is status of Captions support on Data API v3?
When will it be available?

Comment: We are hoping to have it in trusted tester in Q1 and available to all developers right after.

Comment: @IbrahimUlukaya For sale: 1 soul asking for v3 caption support in return.

Comment: Add +1 soul if the new API should provide (documented) support for [binary caption files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25219807).

Comment: New API will support binary caption files and we hope to release it in weeks time.

Comment: @ibrahim-ulukaya, as it seems, this odd restriction remains in v3.0, does it?
`"Whilst v2 of the YouTube Data API restricted access to the caption information to the person who uploaded the video it seems like a very odd restriction"`

Comment: @IbrahimUlukaya It's still impossible to list/download captions without authenticating and getting permission from the video owner? I can't think of a reason for this.

Comment: @ibrahim-ulukaya there is mysterious behaviour, we can't understand why some captions are downloadable and other not, please have a look at my response [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30653865/downloading-captions-always-returns-a-403/42723268#42723268) and if you can add some insight would be great. It's not about who owns the video btw.

Answer (score 0):

They finally introduced the feature:

```
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions
```