# Youtube-API: Upload binary captions file (ebu-stl)

Tags: youtube-api, binaryfiles, closed-captions

Youtube supports some binary caption file formats, [such as ebu-stl.](http://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2734698?hl=en&ref_topic=3014331)

I've got an *.stl file that uploads and processes just fine when I upload it via the web interface. But when I try to upload it via the API v2 with a POST request, it does not seem to recognize the file format properly. [The POST request looks like this](http://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_captions#Create_Caption_Track):

```
POST /feeds/api/videos/VIDEO_ID/captions HTTP/1.1
Host: gdata.youtube.com
Content-Type: application/vnd.youtube.timedtext; charset=UTF-8
Content-Language: en
Slug: Title of caption track
Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN
GData-Version: 2
X-GData-Key: key=DEVELOPER_KEY

<Caption File Data>
```

This is how the *.stl file uploaded via the API looks on the website. There should be several lines with readable text.
[image: Ebu-Stl uploaded via Api]

Everything works fine when I upload a utf8 plain text subtitle file (eg *.vtt) with the same code. Furthermore, if I upload the stl file once via the web interface and once via the API, [and retrieve both files through the API afterwards](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_captions#Retrieve_Caption_Track), they are byte-identical.

It looks like an encoding issue  to me- youtube receives the file correctly, but probably parses the entire binary file as UTF-8. However, youtube responds with a 4xx error when I ommit either *charset=* or *Content-Language*.

Is it possible to upload binary caption files? I would also appreciate confirmation in case it is not possible.

[Minimalistic stl file if you want to try it yourself (hex dump).](http://pastebin.com/wkScEM0i) Read it as (ruby):

```
stl = hex.chars.each_slice(2).map{|x|x.join.to_i(16)}.pack('C*')
```

Comment: API V2 is deprecated, use the API V3

Comment: I know, and I would use it, if it supported captions http://apiblog.youtube.com/2014/03/committing-to-youtube-data-api-v3.html?m=1 Unless they added support for captions recently?

Comment: you're right, i didn't notice that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

API v2 is now officially deprecated. As of April 2, the API v3 now [officially support captions](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions). Binary caption files are supported, too.

The documentation is lacking some details as to the raw HTTP requests. You could try using [one of their libraries](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/).

I used their python script and took a look at the request it made. For reference, here's a minimal working HTTP request for uploading a binary subtitle/captions file.

The [docs aren't mentioning](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/insert) this parameter, but setting `uploadType=multipart` is important, the API returns an error otherwise.

```
POST /upload/youtube/v3/captions?uploadType=multipart&part=id,snippet&sync=false HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Accept: */*
Authorization: Bearer {AUTH_TOKEN}
X-GData-Key: key={YOUR_KEY}
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary================83250640405719953005==
Content-Length: 7147
Expect: 100-continue

--===============83250640405719953005==
Content-Type: application/json
MIME-Version: 1.0

{"snippet":{"videoId":"Agn_uesF248","language":"en","name":"Subtitle Test 2","isDraft":false}}
--===============83250640405719953005==
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: application/sla
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

{BINARY_CAPTION_FILE_DATA}
--===============83250640405719953005==--
```

`application/sla` are ebu-stl caption files. Use `text/plain` for plain text subtitles (.srt, .vtt, .ass, &c.).

Replace `{AUTH_TOKEN}` and `{YOUR_KEY}` with [the proper authorization credentials](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication) for the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl`; and `{BINARY_CAPTION_FILE_DATA}` with the file you wish to upload.