# How to add Captions to Youtube video using Youtube API v3?

Tags: api, video, youtube, subtitle, captions

I used the Youtube API v3 example to successfully upload a video. I can't find how to programmatically add subtitles to the video.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#upload_a_video

Comment: Captions are supported now. I added a sample HTTP request as [an answer to my question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29470703/3925216). The docs [can be found here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions).