# How can I get the cc subtitle of a YouTube video in the the YouTube api v3

Tags: android, youtube-api

How can I get the cc subtitle of a YouTube video using the YouTube API v3 for android?

And what's the difference between the subtitles "english", "english auto-generated" and "english automatic"?

Comment: Auto-generated uses speech recognition to... well... automatically generate subtitles. "english" has been written by a person, most likely the uploader of the video.

Answer (score 1):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/captions#captions-list), you need to call the [captions.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/list) method to retrieve a list of caption tracks that are available for a specific video. Set the [videoId](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/list#parameters) parameter value to the YouTube video ID that uniquely identifies the video for which you are retrieving captions.

```
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.captions.list?part=snippet&videoId=PRU2ShMzQRg
```

Here is an [example](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java#create_and_manage_youtube_video_caption_tracks) that demonstrates how to use the API methods to create and manage YouTube video caption tracks.

Check this related SO question: [How to add Captions to Youtube video using Youtube API v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27913273/how-to-add-captions-to-youtube-video-using-youtube-api-v3)

**UPDATE:**

Check this [example](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/list#examples).

```
/**
     * Returns a list of caption tracks. (captions.listCaptions)
     *
     * @param videoId The videoId parameter instructs the API to return the
     * caption tracks for the video specified by the video id.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private static List<Caption> listCaptions(String videoId) throws IOException {
      // Call the YouTube Data API's captions.list method to
      // retrieve video caption tracks.
      CaptionListResponse captionListResponse = youtube.captions().
          list("snippet", videoId).execute();

      List<Caption> captions = captionListResponse.getItems();
      // Print information from the API response.
      System.out.println("\n============ Returned Caption Tracks ============\n");
      CaptionSnippet snippet;
      for (Caption caption : captions) {
          snippet = caption.getSnippet();
          System.out.println("  - ID: " + caption.getId());
          System.out.println("  - Name: " + snippet.getName());
          System.out.println("  - Language: " + snippet.getLanguage());
          System.out.println("\n----------------------------------------------\n");
      }

      return captions;
    }
```

Comment: thank @abielita, after call the captions.list method, i received like that:
[link](http://imgur.com/mBUy18e) **show image here**
how can i get list captions from this result?

Comment: please tell me how can i retrieve list captions from result after call the captions.list method?
after call the captions.list method, i received result [like that](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/captions?part=snippet&videoId=PRU2ShMzQRg&fields=etag%2CeventId%2Citems%2Ckind%2CvisitorId&key=AIzaSyACXxwTh1iOSpgKGDVkXRJcsbRN19j2_nk)

Comment: Please check my updated answer. Let me know if it works.

Comment: i tried that code, but i got  [error](http://imgur.com/M9jiDYW)
http://imgur.com/M9jiDYW
please help me resolve it. i use youtube api v3.