# How to display aside subtitles of an embedded youtube video?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

Could you help me please to solve this problem, I'm stuck

I want to display subtitles of an embedded youtube video out of the video player box to allow the user to copy and paste it somewhere in order to easily learn from it.
I've already prepared the subtitle of that video in VTT format and it's locally saved. Now my concern is to display subtitles alongside that video, I mean each sentence spoken must be simultaneously displayed in the subtitle side.

[image: 1]

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="thumbnail">
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="<%= lugha.video %>"></iframe>
</div>
<h4 class="title" style="font-weight: bold;"><%=lugha.title%></h4>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="well well-lg">
<!-- Subs here -->
                
<div>
</div>
</div>
```

Embedded video link

```
var data = [
{
title: "War room",
video: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/Hk_m7HUoaUA?controls=0&amp;clip=UgkxDvl5kU8Mri2usSYI5v0W5S4zfPw_oWtG&amp;clipt=EO3BAxifswY"
}
```

One part of the subtitles from a locally saved vtt file

```
WEBVTT - Some title

00:01.220 --> 00:03.100
You can't have my marriage.

00:03.680 --> 00:05.510
You can't have my daughter.

00:05.760 --> 00:07.575
And you sure can't have my man.

00:08.195 --> 00:10.425
This house is under new management.

00:10.715 --> 00:13.045
And that means you are out.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Using the `<track>` element

The [`<track>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/track) is the native way to provide captions etc. for media.

We can use it to parse [WebVTT](https://www.w3.org/TR/webvtt1/) files. The parsed [`TextTrackCue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextTrackCue)s can be accessed via [`HTMLTrackElement.track`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTrackElement):

```js
const trackElement = document.createElement("track");
trackElement.src = getVttUrl();

// `track` now contains all cues
const track = trackElement.track;

function getVttUrl() {
  // Some external resources are disallowed in StackOverflow snippets.
  // Here I'm blobifying the VTT-file's content:
  const vtt = `WEBVTT

00:00:00.000 --> 00:00:00.999  line:80%
Hildy!

00:00:01.000 --> 00:00:01.499 line:80%
How are you?

00:00:01.500 --> 00:00:02.999 line:80%
Tell me, is the lord of the universe in?

00:00:03.000 --> 00:00:04.299 line:80%
Yes, he's in - in a bad humor

00:00:04.300 --> 00:00:06.000 line:80%
Somebody must've stolen the crown jewels
`;

  const vttBlob = new Blob([vtt], { type: "text/vtt" });

  return URL.createObjectURL(vttBlob);
}
```

### With the `cuechange` event

We can add the `<track>` element to a media element, so that it activates the correct cues accordingly.

Setting a [`TextTrack`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextTrack)'s [`mode` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextTrack/mode) to "`hidden`" hides it, but it can still be used programmatically. We can add a listener for its [`cuechange` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextTrack/cuechange_event):

```js
const video = document.querySelector("video");
const captions = document.getElementById("captions");

const trackElement = document.createElement("track");
trackElement.src = getVttUrl();
video.append(trackElement);

const track = trackElement.track;
track.mode = "hidden";

track.addEventListener("cuechange", () => {
  captions.replaceChildren(...Array.from(track.activeCues).map(cue => cue.getCueAsHTML()));
});

function getVttUrl() {
  const vtt = `WEBVTT

00:00:00.000 --> 00:00:00.999  line:80%
Hildy!

00:00:01.000 --> 00:00:01.499 line:80%
How are you?

00:00:01.500 --> 00:00:02.999 line:80%
Tell me, is the lord of the universe in?

00:00:03.000 --> 00:00:04.299 line:80%
Yes, he's in - in a bad humor

00:00:04.300 --> 00:00:06.000 line:80%
Somebody must've stolen the crown jewels
`;

  const vttBlob = new Blob([vtt], { type: "text/vtt" });
  
  return URL.createObjectURL(vttBlob);
}
```

```html
<head><base href="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net"></head>
<body>
  <video controls width=320 src="/media/cc0-videos/friday.mp4"></video>
  <p id="captions"></p>
</body>
```

### With the media's `timeupdate` event

I also tried the video's [`timeupdate` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/timeupdate_event), since their rate of fire depends on the browser's implementation:

```js
const video = document.querySelector("video");
const captions = document.getElementById("captions");

const trackElement = document.createElement("track");
trackElement.src = getVttUrl();
video.append(trackElement);

const track = trackElement.track;
track.mode = "hidden";

video.addEventListener("timeupdate", () => {
  captions.replaceChildren(...Array.from(track.activeCues).map(cue => cue.getCueAsHTML()));
});

function getVttUrl() {
  const vtt = `WEBVTT

00:00:00.000 --> 00:00:00.999  line:80%
Hildy!

00:00:01.000 --> 00:00:01.499 line:80%
How are you?

00:00:01.500 --> 00:00:02.999 line:80%
Tell me, is the lord of the universe in?

00:00:03.000 --> 00:00:04.299 line:80%
Yes, he's in - in a bad humor

00:00:04.300 --> 00:00:06.000 line:80%
Somebody must've stolen the crown jewels
`;

  const vttBlob = new Blob([vtt], { type: "text/vtt" });
  
  return URL.createObjectURL(vttBlob);
}
```

```html
<head><base href="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net"></head>
<body>
  <video controls width=320 src="/media/cc0-videos/friday.mp4"></video>
  <p id="captions"></p>
</body>
```

**Note**: Keep the `<track>` element added to the media, so that [`activeCues`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextTrack/activeCues) is still kept live!

### With `requestAnimationFrame()`

Technically, using the [`requestAnimationFrame()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) should provide the most up-to-date captions possible, since it fires before *every* frame:

```js
const video = document.querySelector("video");
const captions = document.getElementById("captions");

const trackElement = document.createElement("track");
trackElement.src = getVttUrl();
video.append(trackElement);

const track = trackElement.track;
track.mode = "hidden";

track.cues; // Accessing `cues` fixes a "not iterable" error (on Chrome)
requestAnimationFrame(function captionsCallback() {
  updateCaptions();
  requestAnimationFrame(captionsCallback);
});

function updateCaptions() {
  captions.replaceChildren(...Array.from(track.activeCues).map(cue => cue.getCueAsHTML()));
}

function getVttUrl() {
  const vtt = `WEBVTT

00:00:00.000 --> 00:00:00.999  line:80%
Hildy!

00:00:01.000 --> 00:00:01.499 line:80%
How are you?

00:00:01.500 --> 00:00:02.999 line:80%
Tell me, is the lord of the universe in?

00:00:03.000 --> 00:00:04.299 line:80%
Yes, he's in - in a bad humor

00:00:04.300 --> 00:00:06.000 line:80%
Somebody must've stolen the crown jewels
`;

  const vttBlob = new Blob([vtt], { type: "text/vtt" });
  
  return URL.createObjectURL(vttBlob);
}
```

```html
<head><base href="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net"></head>
<body>
  <video controls width=320 src="/media/cc0-videos/friday.mp4"></video>
  <p id="captions"></p>
</body>
```

We can decouple it from `TextTrack`'s `activeCues` by implementing a custom "activeness evaluation" using [`HTMLMediaElement.currentTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime). This may be "even more" live:

```js
const video = document.querySelector("video");
const captions = document.getElementById("captions");

const trackElement = document.createElement("track");
trackElement.src = getVttUrl();
video.append(trackElement);

const track = trackElement.track;
track.mode = "hidden";

track.cues; // Accessing `cues` fixes a "not iterable" error (on Chrome)
requestAnimationFrame(function captionsCallback() {
  updateCaptions();
  requestAnimationFrame(captionsCallback);
});

function updateCaptions() {
  const activeCues = Array.from(track.cues).filter(cue => {
    // Check according to:
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebVTT_API#cue_timings (see "Non-overlapping cue timing examples")
    return cue.startTime <= video.currentTime && cue.endTime > video.currentTime;
  });
  captions.replaceChildren(...activeCues.map(cue => cue.getCueAsHTML()));
}

function getVttUrl() {
  const vtt = `WEBVTT

00:00:00.000 --> 00:00:00.999  line:80%
Hildy!

00:00:01.000 --> 00:00:01.499 line:80%
How are you?

00:00:01.500 --> 00:00:02.999 line:80%
Tell me, is the lord of the universe in?

00:00:03.000 --> 00:00:04.299 line:80%
Yes, he's in - in a bad humor

00:00:04.300 --> 00:00:06.000 line:80%
Somebody must've stolen the crown jewels
`;

  const vttBlob = new Blob([vtt], { type: "text/vtt" });
  
  return URL.createObjectURL(vttBlob);
}
```

```html
<head><base href="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net"></head>
<body>
  <video controls width=320 src="/media/cc0-videos/friday.mp4"></video>
  <p id="captions"></p>
</body>
```

---

## Comparing the methods

Here you can try the methods from above yourself:

```js
const video = document.querySelector("video");

const trackElement = document.createElement("track");
trackElement.src = getVttUrl();
video.append(trackElement);

const track = trackElement.track;
track.mode = "hidden";

(function captionsCuechange() {
  const captions = document.getElementById("cap-cuechange");
  track.addEventListener("cuechange", () => {
    captions.replaceChildren(...Array.from(track.activeCues).map(cue => cue.getCueAsHTML()));
  });
})();

(function captionsTimeupdate() {
  const captions = document.getElementById("cap-timeupdate");

  video.addEventListener("timeupdate", () => {
    captions.replaceChildren(...Array.from(track.activeCues).map(cue => cue.getCueAsHTML()));
  });
})();

(function captionsRequestAnimationFrame() {
  const captions = document.getElementById("cap-frame");
  
  track.cues; // Accessing `cues` fixes a "not iterable" error (on Chrome)
  requestAnimationFrame(function captionsCallback() {
    updateCaptions();
    requestAnimationFrame(captionsCallback);
  });
  
  function updateCaptions() {
    const cuesAsHTML = Array.from(track.activeCues).map(cue => cue.getCueAsHTML());
    captions.replaceChildren(...cuesAsHTML);
  }
})();

(function captionsRequestAnimationFrameAndCurrentTime() {
  const captions = document.getElementById("cap-frame-current");
  
  track.cues; // Accessing `cues` fixes a "not iterable" error (on Chrome)
  requestAnimationFrame(function captionsCallback() {
    updateCaptions();
    requestAnimationFrame(captionsCallback);
  });
  
  function updateCaptions() {
    const activeCues = Array.from(track.cues).filter(cue => {
      return cue.startTime <= video.currentTime && cue.endTime > video.currentTime;
    });
    const cuesAsHTML = activeCues.map(cue => cue.getCueAsHTML());
    captions.replaceChildren(...cuesAsHTML);
  }
})();

function getVttUrl() {
  const vtt = `WEBVTT

00:00:00.000 --> 00:00:00.999  line:80%
Hildy!

00:00:01.000 --> 00:00:01.499 line:80%
How are you?

00:00:01.500 --> 00:00:02.999 line:80%
Tell me, is the lord of the universe in?

00:00:03.000 --> 00:00:04.299 line:80%
Yes, he's in - in a bad humor

00:00:04.300 --> 00:00:06.000 line:80%
Somebody must've stolen the crown jewels
`;

  const vttBlob = new Blob([vtt], { type: "text/vtt" });
  
  return URL.createObjectURL(vttBlob);
}
```

```css
.caption {min-height: 1lh}
```

```html
<head><base href="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net"></head>
<body>
  <video controls width=320 src="/media/cc0-videos/friday.mp4"></video>
  <div>
    <p>On <code>cuechange</code>:</p>
    <p id="cap-cuechange" class="caption"></p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>On <code>timeupdate</code>:</p>
    <p id="cap-timeupdate" class="caption"></p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>With <code>requestAnimationFrame()</code>:</p>
    <p id="cap-frame" class="caption"></p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>With <code>requestAnimationFrame()</code> and <code>currentTime</code>:</p>
    <p id="cap-frame-current" class="caption"></p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Also try scrubbing the timeline and see how the captions react!

**Note**: You may want to try the custom activeness check with the other events as well.

Comment: thank you so much, all these methods works just perfectly and I prefer the cuechange one. But I want to know if I have a webvtt file locally saved, how to load it like in an URL? example : trackElement.src = "/media/cc0-videos/friday.vtt" ; Is it possible?

Comment: @Mata28 Will you serve the webpage from the same machine where the VTT-file is saved? If so then yes, your URL looks fine.

Comment: yes that's the case. And is it possible to use these methods with an embedded youtube video with an iframe tag, or it's just possible with the video tag?

Comment: @Mata28 [Cross-site scripting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#cross-origin_script_api_access) is limited, but you can use the [YouTube Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference). You can't use `TextTrack.activeCues` or the `cuechange` event as above, but you can [get the player's current time](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#getCurrentTime) to find the active cues with a "custom activeness check".

Comment: @Mata28  For performance reasons, you may want to only find the active cues continuously when the [player's state](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#onStateChange) is "[`playing`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#getPlayerState)".

Comment: Great thank you @OskarGrosser. If i try this URL way, Example : trackElement.src = "/media/cc0-videos/friday.vtt" how could I declare const vttBlob?

Comment: Are there method to get this subtitles from loaded embed videoplayer object?

Comment: @user1852788 If it is not exposed in some way, then no. A quick search showed me [how to request captions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36708264/13561410).