# Unable to download closed captions in Youtube API v3

Tags: php, youtube-api, google-api-php-client, closed-captions, youtube-data-api

Im using the PHP example code given in Youtube API v3 :  https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/download , to download captions from 3rd party, publicly available YouTube videos in my webapp i.e. I have NOT uploaded the content on Youtube.

I am able to get access to the **list** of caption tracks, but unable to **download** the caption using the caption track ID from the received list.

The error that shows up upon attempting to DOWNLOAD is:

> Error calling GET https://
>   www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/captions/Lw0e5xDNU17GFafOl8DcyeOtwzWJTf9V?tfmt=srt&alt=media:
>   (404) Not Found

(I have tried removing tfmt (optional parameter), but still gives an error.)

But the error is different for attempting to DELETE captions:

> Error calling DELETE https://
>   www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/captions?id=Lw0e5xDNU17GFafOl8DcyeOtwzWJTf9V:
>   (403) Forbidden

Therefore it seems that captions.download is NOT forbidden for users other than owner (just like the captions.list is NOT forbidden) and therefore I would like to use this data for my webapp.

Any help is gratefully received.

Thanks,

Nikhil

Comment: Try using the URL format for the delete call with the ID as a query parameter instead of the one you are using.  Their documentation for the URL of getting could be wrong.  Also below they mention that ID is a query parameter.

Comment: Ya good observation that they mention ID as a query parameter in the documentation.. Still tried that Brian & got an error like "Unsupported output format". Will update the exact error message here after sometime.

Comment: did you find any resolution over this issue, right now i am fetching same kind of issue, and i could not get over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found another way to access any YouTube video's caption data.
The code is written in Ruby.

[Read Youtube transcript (captions) from any public Youtube video](https://github.com/joshlarsen/yt-captions)

Works great, I just need to find a way to integrate this with my webapp.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried the URL you mentioned in a browser and in the API explorer, and in both cases I received a 401 when I had no oAuth token and a 403 when I had an access token (since I'm not the owner), so the endpoints are acting as intended; according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/download), downloading captions requires oAuth consent from the owner of the video.

Perhaps, if you're getting 404s instead, there's a problem in the PHP library?

Comment: 403 error is expected in Delete, insert or upload methods if you are not the owner, but I'm sure you won't get a "403 Forbidden" error when using **list** captions. Similarly I expect download.captions to work for non-owners too.
Also, the documentation doesn't say anywhere that only owner can download the captions.

The only problem I could think of in PHP library (Google/Service/Youtube.php) is about passing id as path parameter.
I tried changing it to query but still error came up saying "Unsupported output format". Then I removed the tmft="srt" parameter, but still it isn't working.

Comment: The documentation says exactly that about downloading captions: "This request requires authorization with at least one of the following scopes (read more about authentication and authorization). https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl" -- that's the scope that grants an app consent to manage a user's YouTube account, thus indicating that only the owner of a video can make the request. More to the point, if you test in the api explorer, you'll see that if you authorize to a video you do own, you get a 200. Note that this was also the behavior in V2 of the API.

Comment: After going through this [stackoverflow Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192214/closed-captions-in-youtube-api-v3?rq=1) , It looked like captions could be downloaded by 3rd party (i.e non-owners) too in v3 API. 

The same line that you mention also exists in listing captions section here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/list , but this works fine. Also no 403 error shows up as in delete method, giving further hope that captions cud be downloaded by third party.

Comment: The SO question you linked to clearly demonstrates that the user wasn't able to download captions. Ibrahim's update to his answer merely states that V3 finally received a captions endpoint, not that users could download them for videos they don't own. Basically, the download endpoint is working exactly as documented; therefore there's no bug (there is in the list endpoint, on the other hand, because according to the documentation it should also require authorization). You can always file a feature request, as there are certainly use cases for needing captions, but for now it's a no go.