# Python sockets error TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' with send function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a program that will open a port on the local machine and let others connect into it via netcat. My current code is.

```
s = socket.socket()
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 12345
s.bind((host, port))

s.listen(5)
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print('Got connection from', addr)
    c.send('Thank you for connecting')
    c.close()
```

I am new to Python and sockets. But when I run this code it will allow me to send a netcat connection with the command:

```
nc 127.0.0.1 12345
```

But then on my Python script I get the error for the c.send:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I am basically just trying to open a port, allow netcat to connect and have a full shell on that machine.

Comment: Have you tried encoding yet?

Comment: No. I can comment out the c.send and it will run. Do you think that string needs to be encoded?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The reason for this error is that in Python 3, strings are Unicode, but when transmitting on the network, the data needs to be bytes instead. So... a couple of suggestions:

1. Suggest using `c.sendall()` instead of `c.send()` to prevent possible issues where you may not have sent the entire msg with one call (see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.sendall)).
2. For literals, add a `'b'` for bytes string: `c.sendall(b'Thank you for connecting')`
3. For variables, you need to encode Unicode strings to byte strings (see below)

Best solution (should work w/both 2.x & 3.x):

```
output = 'Thank you for connecting'
c.sendall(output.encode('utf-8'))
```

*Epilogue/background*: this isn't an issue in Python 2 because strings are bytes strings already -- your OP code would work perfectly in that environment. Unicode strings were added to Python in releases 1.6 & 2.0 but took a back seat until 3.0 when they became the default string type. Also see [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054527) as well as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34283178).

Comment: Thank you for this. This is very helpful and also answers my question.

Answer (score 14):

You can decode it to str with `receive.decode('utf_8')`.

Answer (score 11):

You can change the send line to this:

```
c.send(b'Thank you for connecting')
```

The `b` makes it bytes instead.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to introduce a method to the file instance that would do the explicit conversion.

```
import types

def _write_str(self, ascii_str):
    self.write(ascii_str.encode('ascii'))

source_file = open("myfile.bin", "wb")
source_file.write_str = types.MethodType(_write_str, source_file)
```

And then you can use it as `source_file.write_str("Hello World")`.