# How to send data over tcp to ESP8266 with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I want to send data from my computer to ESP8266 over TCP. I wanted to do this with python. I programmed ESP with arduino-language with libraries for it, and reciving is simply:

```
while(client.available()){
    String in = client.readStringUntil('~'); 
    //i use '~' instead of '\n' as end character because i often can't send '\n' from tcp android apps
    ...
}
```

I use built-in socket library for python, this is how i try to send data:

```
server_ip = '192.168.1.100'
server_port = 3000
soc = socket.socket()
soc.connect((server_ip, server_port))
soc.send("mydata")
```

but i'm still getting error "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'". I tried .sendall etc, and sometimes they work, but then my ESP restarts for some reason, maybe encoding? Could someone give me staight path to just send basic string, even with ascii-only characters?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python sockets error TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' with send function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42612002)

Comment: I tried .encode(), and it works for python, but then my ESP restets:
ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:4, boot mode:(3,7)

Comment: That's a different unrelated problem. If you expect us to fix all your problems with the code, then the question is too broad.

Comment: I can't seem to understand your socket communication architecture. Which one is the socket server? The python or the esp? Both of them seem to be using client mode.

Comment: ESP is server. I have table of WiFiClient's. When server have new client, i attach it to unused client object and then do all methods for each client object.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i did

```
.sendall(text.encode('utf-8')
```

and figured out that i forget about '~', now everything works :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this project at github for communication between nodemcu and python over ip

https://github.com/wahajmurtaza/NodeMCU-Python-Wifi

Comment: Hello Helper, appreciate your help. However, the link only answers are not exactly welcomed on Stack Overflow. It is expected that you provide the precise answer and add a link as a supportive.  See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)