# Code works in Python 2 but not Python3 TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle, python-2.x

The following code works in Python 2.7:

```
import os
import pickle

modelpath = "models/"

gmm_files = [os.path.join(modelpath,fname) for fname in 
          os.listdir(modelpath) if fname.endswith('.gmm')]

models    = [pickle.load(open(fname,'r')) for fname in gmm_files]
```

However, when I run the code in Python3, I get the following error from the last line:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

In order to get a better idea, I tried printing `print([type(open(fname,'r')) for fname in gmm_files])` in both versions and found out that in python 2 the type is `<type 'file'>` and in Python 3 the type is `<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>`.

I've checked out these stackoverflow questions but neither of them have helpful answers for this:

[python 3.5: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' when writing to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054527/python-3-5-typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-when-writing-t?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

[Python sockets error TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' with send function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42612002/python-sockets-error-typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-with?noredirect=1&lq=1&utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

UPDATE

A bunch of the answers here said to change `open(fname, 'r')`to `open(fname, 'rb')` but that just leads to another error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: You need to open the file in binary mode, rather than (the default) text mode: `open(fname,'rb')`

Comment: I also suggest using the the pathlib library rather than os. In my opinion it is a lot nicer to work with.

Comment: Thanks everyone. @TomDalton I updated the question to show what happens when I implement changing `r` to `rb`

Comment: Are you trying to unpickle data in python 3.x that you pickled with 2.7? Can you post the full traceback of the error?

Comment: (It's probably worth asking this as a completely new question)

Answer (score 2):

As the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.load) for the `pickle.load` method says (emphasis mine):

> The argument file must have two methods, a read() method that takes an integer argument, and a readline() method that requires no arguments. *Both methods should return bytes.*

`open(stuff, 'r')` will open the file for reading *text*, not raw bytes. Thus, `open(stuff, 'r').read` will return `str`, not `bytes`. To fix that, open the file in binary mode: `open(stuff, 'rb')`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and got the error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: @Philip7899, since you couldn't've gotten this error from opening the file or reading data from it (unless you typo'd somewhere), this means that you did manage to start the unpickling process, which faced some encoding issues. This, however, is a different problem and doesn't have to do with the original question. You should search for its cause in the pickled data.

Answer (score 2):

Ref https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pickle.html#pickle.load, the file-like object you pass to `pickle.load` needs to return binary data. Files are opened in text-mode by default, which is why you're seeing this error. If you open the file in binary mode (by adding `'b'` to the mode), everything should be work.

E.g.

```
models = [pickle.load(open(fname, 'rb')) for fname in gmm_files]
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and get another error, which I have updated the question with.  When I do that, i get the error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`