# Python socket server - TypeError: a bites like object is required, not "str"

Tags: python, html, sockets, encoding, server

I found this thread: [Python sockets error TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' with send function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42612002/python-sockets-error-typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-with?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But my problem is - when i add a `b` in front of my HTML string or when i encode it, i no longer get an error when opening the site on my browser - but i also no longer SEE the site! I just get a blank white screen, sometimes an error that says it cant load the site.
Why is this and how can i prevent it? It all works fine in micropython, but not in python 3 that im using on my computer.

This is the code im using:

```
    # Complete project details at https://RandomNerdTutorials.com
import socket
html = b"""<html><head><title>TEST</title>TEST</head></html>"""

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('', 80))
s.listen()

while True:
    print(s)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print('Got a connection from %s' % str(addr))
    response = html
    conn.send(html)
    conn.close()
```

Comment: Decode the bytes you receive before you render HTML. Using decode function https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode

Comment: I get that, but where do i do the decoding when im opening the site in a browser?

Comment: you edited your comment so I didn't see the code. You're sending only html body, you need to send whole HTTP request so browser can properly handle it.

Comment: Oh, but why does it work on my esp32 with micropython? im using the exact same sniplet there and i can open the site just fine if its hosted on the esp32 with micropython