# Python sockets TypeError: error bytes-like object is required, not 'str' with send function

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I am try to build simple `Client-Sever`:

**Server**

```
import socket

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
name = socket.gethostname()
ip = '127.0.0.1'
port = 4500
address = (ip, port)
server.bind(address)
server.listen(1)
print('Start listening on', ip, ':', port)
client, addr = server.accept()
print('Received connection from', addr[0], ':', addr[1])

while True:
    data = client.recv(1024)
    print('Received', data, 'from the client')
    print('Processing data...')
    if data == 'Hello server':
        print('Processing done.\nReplay sent')
        client.send('Hello client')
    elif data == 'Disconnect':
        print('Goodbye')
        client.send('Goodbye')
        client.close()
        break
    else:
        print('Invalid data')
        client.send('Invalid data')
```

**Client**

```
import socket

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

ip = '127.0.0.1'
port = 4500
address = (ip, port)

message='mymessage'

client=socket.socket()
client.connect(address)
client.sendall(message.encode('utf-8'))
```

So after the `server` is running and i try to execute my `client` code i got this `server` error:

> Start listening on 127.0.0.1 : 4500 Received connection from 127.0.0.1
>   : 57503 Received b'mymessage' from the client Processing data...
>   Invalid data Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\jim\tmp\server.py", line
>   28, in 
>       client.send('Invalid data') TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42612002/python-sockets-error-typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-with?noredirect=1&lq=1) answer but it seems not helped

**Edit**

On `server` side i add this line:

```
modifiedMessage = client.recvfrom(data.decode('utf-8'))
```

But this crash with this `error`:

> modifiedMessage = client.recvfrom(data.decode('utf-8')) TypeError:
>   'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: Like the error message says, and like you already do in the last line, you need to `encode` your string or otherwise take care to serialize it into `bytes`.

Comment: but i did it using .encode...

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: Your update asks about a new bug which you introduced in addition to the ones you had. Where you `print` a string you also attempt to `send` a string; you need to `send` a `bytes` object, not a string. Maybe see also https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html and in particular the slides about "sandwiching".

Comment: The `b'mymessage'` is fine, but the stuff like `client.send('Hello client')` is not. The simple solution when you want to send hard-coded ASCII is to use literal `bytes` strings, eg `client.send(b'Hello client')`