# python prepared requests - removing unwanted header

Tags: python, python-requests, http-headers, urllib3

I'm having troubles with this code chunk:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    _hs = s.headers
    
    req = requests.Request('POST', url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
    prepared_req = req.prepare()
    if 'Content-Length' in prepared_req.headers:
        prepared_req.headers.pop('Content-Length')
    rsp = s.send(prepared_req, timeout=self._TIMEOUT)
    try:
        rsp.raise_for_status()
    except requests.HTTPError:
        self._logger.exception("error in retrieving response from %s -- response content: %s",
                                        url, rsp.content)
        raise
    return rsp.json()
```

`Content-Length` is correctly removed from the PreparedRequest headers, however during `send` something goes wrong:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/projects/MyProj/my-http-client/my_http_client/http_client.py", line 297, in _http_post
    rsp = s.send(prepared_req, timeout=self._TIMEOUT)
  File "/home/user/venvs/my-http-client-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/venvs/my-http-client-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 472, in send
    low_conn.send(i)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 975, in send
    self.sock.sendall(d)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

same thing happens if I remove the header with `del`:

```
del prepared_req.headers['Content-Length']
```

anyone does know what's wrong? without the `headers.pop`, everything runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

As per this answer to a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42612002/python-sockets-error-typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-with/42612820), in python3 all strings are Unicode by default but when sending over a network need to be converted to bytes.

I suspect the issue is with the line `data=json.dumps`, as dumping the data converts it to a string not bytes:

```
In [1]: data=json.dumps(dict(a='somestring'))                                                                                                                                 

In [2]: data                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[3]: '{"a": "somestring"}'

In [4]: type(data)                                                                                                                                                            
Out[5]: str
```

The solution is to encode the string to bytes:

```
In [6]: data=json.dumps(dict(a='somestring')).encode('utf-8')                                                                                                                 

In [7]: data                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[8]: b'{"a": "somestring"}'

In [9]: type(data)                                                                                                                                                            
Out[10]: bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

tried that, now I have this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/venvs/my-app-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 470, in send
    low_conn.send(hex(len(i))[2:].encode('utf-8'))
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

weird, on the official requests docs the way to remove header seems to be exactly that
https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#prepared-requests

Comment: I think you meant to put this as a comment on my answer as it's not an answer to your original problem. It's impossible to say what caused that error from just that snippet, but the `TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()` tells you that `len(i)` is failing as `i` in an int not an iterable as is expected.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing the below error when you remove Content-Length:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/venvs/my-app-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 470, in send
    low_conn.send(hex(len(i))[2:].encode('utf-8'))
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

You need to set the request body to None for it to work when you remove Content-Length:

```
del prepared_request.headers['Content-Length']
prepared_request.body = None
```

This is only for get request where you dont need the body.