# Why am I getting 'TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'' when running my WHOIS script in the Linux terminal?

Tags: python, linux, bash, whois, pywhois

I am creating a basic "whois" script, but it is not working.  When I try to run it in the Linux terminal, it returns the error:

> "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'" indicated in
> the line of code: `s.send(sys.argv[1]+"\r"+"\n")`.

**consulta.py**

```
#!/usr/share/python
import socket
import sys
import pyfiglet

ascii_banner = pyfiglet.figlet_format("WHOIS - Gustang")
print (ascii_banner)

reg = "whois.godaddy.com"

if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((reg, 43))
        s.send(sys.argv[1]+"\r"+"\n")
        resp = s.recv(1024)
        print (resp)
else:
        print ("Modo de Uso: IPv4 + Porta")
        print ("Exemplo: 255.255.255.255 21")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python sockets error TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' with send function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42612002/python-sockets-error-typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-with)

Comment: Did you check the documentation? https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html

Comment: Not related to the main problem, but `if len(sys.argv) == 2` should be `if len(sys.argv) == 3` for the given example. Also when given an example, better give the full program call such as `print ("Exemplo:\n\t./consulta.py 255.255.255.255 21")`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send bytes. The response will also be bytes.

With irrelevant parts of the code removed...

```
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM
from sys import argv

HOST = 'whois.godaddy.com'
PORT = 43
CONNECTION = HOST, PORT
CRLF = b'\r\n'
BUFSIZ = 16

def get_response(s: socket) -> str:
    ba = bytearray()
    while True:
        ba.extend(s.recv(BUFSIZ))
        if ba.endswith(CRLF):
            break
    return ba.decode()

if len(argv) == 2:
    with socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.connect(CONNECTION)
        s.send(f'{argv[1]}\r\n'.encode())
        print(get_response(s))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the corrections.
Can you explain this part better:                                                                                                            "CRLF = b'\r\n'
BUFSIZ = 16

def get_response(s: socket) -> str:
    ba = bytearray()
    while True:
        ba.extend(s.recv(BUFSIZ))
        if ba.endswith(CRLF):
            break
    return ba.decode()"

Comment: @Gustang It would be quite difficult to offer you tutoring via stack**overflow** comments. There are many free resources for learning Python. Start here: https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/