# Python: Downloading captions from YouTube

Tags: python, oauth, youtube, youtube-data-api

Hello I tried to download captions from a YouTube video with YouTube data API.
I customized [the example code](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/download) produced by YouTube.

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
    # Usage example:
    # python captions.py --videoid='<video_id>' --name='<name>' --file='<file>' --language='<language>' --action='action'

    import httplib2
    import os
    import sys

    from apiclient.discovery import build_from_document
    from apiclient.errors import HttpError
    from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
    from oauth2client.file import Storage
    from oauth2client.tools import argparser, run_flow


    # The CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE variable specifies the name of a file that contains

    # the OAuth 2.0 information for this application, including its client_id and
    # client_secret. You can acquire an OAuth 2.0 client ID and client secret from
    # the {{ Google Cloud Console }} at
    # {{ https://cloud.google.com/console }}.
    # Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
    # For more information about using OAuth2 to access the YouTube Data API, see:
    #   https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication
    # For more information about the client_secrets.json file format, see:
    #   https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets
    CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client_secrets.json"

    # This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows for full read/write access to the
    # authenticated user's account and requires requests to use an SSL connection.
    YOUTUBE_READ_WRITE_SSL_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl"
    YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
    YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"

    # This variable defines a message to display if the CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE is
    # missing.
    MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE = """
    WARNING: Please configure OAuth 2.0

    To make this sample run you will need to populate the client_secrets.json file
    found at:
       %s
    with information from the APIs Console
    https://console.developers.google.com

    For more information about the client_secrets.json file format, please visit:
        https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets
    """ % os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
                                       CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE))

    # Authorize the request and store authorization credentials.
    def get_authenticated_service(args):
      flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, scope=YOUTUBE_READ_WRITE_SSL_SCOPE,
        message=MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE)

      storage = Storage("%s-oauth2.json" % sys.argv[0])
      credentials = storage.get()

      if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
        credentials = run_flow(flow, storage, args)

      # Trusted testers can download this discovery document from the developers page
      # and it should be in the same directory with the code.
      with open("youtube-v3-api-captions.json", "r", encoding="UTF-8", newline="") as f:
        doc = f.read()
        return build_from_document(doc, http=credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http()))


    # Call the API's captions.list method to list the existing caption tracks.
    def list_captions(youtube, video_id):
      results = youtube.captions().list(
        part="snippet",
        videoId=video_id
      ).execute()

      for item in results["items"]:
        id = item["id"]
        name = item["snippet"]["name"]
        language = item["snippet"]["language"]
        print ("Caption track '%s(%s)' in '%s' language.") % (name, id, language)

      return results["items"]


    # Call the API's captions.insert method to upload a caption track in draft status.
    def upload_caption(youtube, video_id, language, name, file):
      insert_result = youtube.captions().insert(
        part="snippet",
        body=dict(
          snippet=dict(
            videoId=video_id,
            language=language,
            name=name,
            isDraft=True
          )
        ),
        media_body=file
      ).execute()

      id = insert_result["id"]
      name = insert_result["snippet"]["name"]
      language = insert_result["snippet"]["language"]
      status = insert_result["snippet"]["status"]
      print ("Uploaded caption track '%s(%s) in '%s' language, '%s' status.") % (name,
          id, language, status)


    # Call the API's captions.update method to update an existing caption track's draft status
    # and publish it. If a new binary file is present, update the track with the file as well.
    def update_caption(youtube, caption_id, file):
      update_result = youtube.captions().update(
        part="snippet",
        body=dict(
          id=caption_id,
          snippet=dict(
            isDraft=False
          )
        ),
        media_body=file
      ).execute()

  name = update_result["snippet"]["name"]
  isDraft = update_result["snippet"]["isDraft"]
  print ("Updated caption track '%s' draft status to be: '%s'") % (name, isDraft)
  if file:
    print ("and updated the track with the new uploaded file.")


# Call the API's captions.download method to download an existing caption track.
def download_caption(youtube, caption_id, tfmt):
  subtitle = youtube.captions().download(
    id=caption_id,
    tfmt=tfmt
  ).execute()

  print ("First line of caption track: %s") % (subtitle)

# Call the API's captions.delete method to delete an existing caption track.
def delete_caption(youtube, caption_id):
  youtube.captions().delete(
    id=caption_id
  ).execute()

  print ("caption track '%s' deleted succesfully") % (caption_id)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  # The "videoid" option specifies the YouTube video ID that uniquely
  # identifies the video for which the caption track will be uploaded.
  argparser.add_argument("--videoid",
    help="Required; ID for video for which the caption track will be uploaded.")
  # The "name" option specifies the name of the caption trackto be used.
  argparser.add_argument("--name", help="Caption track name", default="YouTube for Developers")
  # The "file" option specifies the binary file to be uploaded as a caption track.
  argparser.add_argument("--file", help="Captions track file to upload")
  # The "language" option specifies the language of the caption track to be uploaded.
  argparser.add_argument("--language", help="Caption track language", default="en")
  # The "captionid" option specifies the ID of the caption track to be processed.
  argparser.add_argument("--captionid", help="Required; ID of the caption track to be processed")
  # The "action" option specifies the action to be processed.
  argparser.add_argument("--action", help="Action", default="all")


  args = argparser.parse_args()

  if (args.action in ('upload', 'list', 'all')):
    if not args.videoid:
          exit("Please specify videoid using the --videoid= parameter.")

  if (args.action in ('update', 'download', 'delete')):
    if not args.captionid:
          exit("Please specify captionid using the --captionid= parameter.")

  if (args.action in ('upload', 'all')):
    if not args.file:
      exit("Please specify a caption track file using the --file= parameter.")
    if not os.path.exists(args.file):
      exit("Please specify a valid file using the --file= parameter.")

  youtube = get_authenticated_service(args)

  try:
    if args.action == 'upload':
      upload_caption(youtube, args.videoid, args.language, args.name, args.file)
    elif args.action == 'list':
      list_captions(youtube, args.videoid)
    elif args.action == 'update':
      update_caption(youtube, args.captionid, args.file);
    elif args.action == 'download':
      download_caption(youtube, args.captionid, 'srt')
    elif args.action == 'delete':
      delete_caption(youtube, args.captionid);
    else:
      # All the available methods are used in sequence just for the sake of an example.
      upload_caption(youtube, args.videoid, args.language, args.name, args.file)
      captions = list_captions(youtube, args.videoid)

      if captions:
        first_caption_id = captions[0]['id'];
        update_caption(youtube, first_caption_id, None);
        download_caption(youtube, first_caption_id, 'srt')
        delete_caption(youtube, first_caption_id);
  except Exception as e:
    print (e)
  else:
    print ("Created and managed caption tracks.")
```

If I run the command

```
python captions.py --videoid='00RxteR1oGQ' --language='en' --action='download'
```

The result is:

> HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/captions?part=snippet&alt=json returned "The video identified by the `videoId` parameter could not be found."

But the video Id I typed apparently exists.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: why hiding the error exception message ? replace `print ("An HTTP error")` by `print(e)`, and update your post then

Comment: Thanks @PRMoureu I've never thought about that way. I edited the question.

Comment: I used the same script/video id but got this error instead `Please specify captionid using the --captionid= parameter.`  This answer should be helpful though I haven't tried the solution used there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41935427/cant-download-video-captions-using-youtube-api-v3-in-python

Comment: I could solve this problem with the source code from there! Many thanks @BernardParah!

Answer (score 8):

```
#download the package by:  pip install pytube
from pytube import YouTube

source = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wjTn_EkgQRg&index=1&list=PLgJ7b1NurjD2oN5ZXbKbPjuI04d_S0V1K')


en_caption = source.captions.get_by_language_code('en')

en_caption_convert_to_srt =(en_caption.generate_srt_captions())

print(en_caption_convert_to_srt)
#save the caption to a file named Output.txt
text_file = open("Output.txt", "w")
text_file.write(en_caption_convert_to_srt)
text_file.close()
```

Comment: It doesn't work anymore...

Answer (score 0):

you have to get the pytube and import youtube package from it
`pip install pytube`

import and specify the link you need to extract captions from

```
from pytube import YouTube
link = YouTube('any video link')
```

you can get a list of the captions available and there code, using the following code

```
#looking for the available captions
av_captions = link.captions
print(av_captions)
```

now to extract the captions and encode them in XML format and then saving them to a flat file using the following code

```
# caption codes format is something like this ['en', 'ar', 'fr']
caption = source.captions.get_by_language_code('One of the available caption codes')
xml_caption = caption.xml_captions #encode in xml format

#saving the the captions to a flat file
with open("output.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(xml_caption)
```