# How can I download YouTube subtitles? (I can't using a simple method with pytube)

Tags: python, youtube, pytube

```
import pytube

yt = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lW2pXu97Yvo')

yt.captions.all()
```

I'm trying this simple code and keep getting this:

[image: Error message]

Can somebody recommend a method of downloading YouTube subtitles?

Comment: May be this link will be useful :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44893271/python-downloading-captions-from-youtube

Comment: It is not, because even though pytube is installed the class YouTube doesn't seem to exist. :/

Comment: It's quite simple, just import YouTube. You only imported pytube. If you want to use YouTube, change it YouTube to pytube.YouTube, or change `import pytube` to `from pytube import YouTube`

Answer (score 3):

You never imported `YouTube`. It's supposed to be:

```py
from pytube3 import YouTube # for Python 3
from pytube import YouTube # for Python 2
yt = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lW2pXu97Yvo')

yt.captions.all()
```

Comment: I recommend you change pytube3 to pytube, because the question uses pytube

Comment: Instead, I'll add an extra line with a comment.