# Youtube data API: caption download API not working with API key

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Youtube caption download API throwing 401 with API key.
https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/captions/id

```json
 "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "API keys are not supported by this API. Expected OAuth2 access token or other authentication credentials that assert a principal. See https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication",
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Login Required.",
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "required",
            "location": "Authorization",
            "locationType": "header"
        }
    ]
}
```

API is throwing 401 error with API key.

Comment: please edit your question and include [example]

Comment: Duplicated with [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30653865).

Answer (score 0):

Error message is legit. Captions require OAuth2 and cannot be fetched with a public API key.

See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/list#auth