# Permission denied on returning captions to YouTube

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have an integration with YouTube to return captions to videos of different YouTube accounts, and I use the YouTube API for this.

The thing is that some accounts are not being authorized to return captions. I made some investigation and I noticed some stuffs:

1. The oauth app seems to intermittently give an unverified warning to users trying to authorize the application to access their youtube account via api;
2. Even the users authorizing their accounts, when I try to return the captions I get an unauthorized message;
3. By digging more, I noticed that the access token had its expiration date to the moment of authorization.
4. The token is not being refreshed, which should be done by the refresh token, and seems to be not working.

Did someone had problems like that? How did you solved? I already tried to get in touch with YouTube support, but they could not give me a solution or a path to do a better investigation.

I was trying getting in touch with YouTube, but it seems that their technical support only replies on Stackoverflow.

[Google saying that the app was not verified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkepa.jpg)

[Status of verified application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irkXD.png)

Comment: Is your application verified? Is your application in production mode?   Please edit your question and include [example]

Comment: Do you have access to these YouTube accounts? Otherwise [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30653865/downloading-captions-always-returns-a-403#comment49414961_30660549) applies.

Comment: The application is verified and in production mode. This problem is only happening on three YouTube accounts. The integration is working properly with other accounts.

The videos are from the linked account.