# Can't use YouTube api to download cc

Tags: youtube-api

I'm trying to get familiar with the YouTube api for a project. I'm using the code provided in the documentation to download the captions with the id=AUieDaa7Bb0_-GBwVIYbXKsnPYAP3Q5FsPB4xMEnMemuWk4L8rU

The code completes the request after I provide it with the credentials but the response says I don't have enough credentials.

I'm using python.

I was expecting to find the close captions in the file I specified but instead I get a negative response. I tried changing videos to see if the problem was the video but I get the same result. I don't know what to change in the code because it's from the documentation and I only changed the OAuth json and the captions id.

Comment: If you are in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30653865/downloading-captions-always-returns-a-403#comment49414961_30660549), then consider using `yt-dlp`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code you're using.