# Attempting to obtain video subtitle error message

Tags: youtube-api

Attempting to obtain video subtitles with an error message. Obtaining video subtitles after authentication with Auth2.0, but unable to obtain subtitles for other videos, only obtaining subtitles for the personal video of the authenticator with Auth2.0. The error message is as follows, but I can confirm that my auth authentication permissions include SSL permissions.

GET https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/captions/AUieDaYqxpKkWtl4KIZ6aCk9-F-uRvshqdX1Es9y1wHe0Z3qzJI?alt=media

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The permissions associated with the request are not sufficient to download the caption track. The request might not be properly authorized, or the video order might not have enabled third-party contributions for this caption.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The permissions associated with the request are not sufficient to download the caption track. The request might not be properly authorized, or the video order might not have enabled third-party contributions for this caption.",
        "domain": "youtube.caption",
        "reason": "forbidden",
        "location": "id",
        "locationType": "parameter"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems it is not possible get the captions from any video - only the owner of said video can download their captions. [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30653865/downloading-captions-always-returns-a-403#comment49414961_30660549).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Downloading captions always returns a 403](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30653865/downloading-captions-always-returns-a-403)