# Youtube Caption Download gives Error 404, the caption id is valid

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to download youtube captions using youtube API, I use a videoID to get caption id, when I try to download video caption using youtubeDataapi playground, I get error 404. I have checked and the video id is valid, and I have enough quote for api call.

Trying to download video captions of a youtube video, expecting a video caption, getting error 404. Used this id

""
{
"kind": "youtube#captionListResponse",
"etag": "QkF_mmYVO0qgPorsWCgqGMfBq4I",
"items": [
{
"kind": "youtube#caption",
"etag": "KWo4Fw_AkcqatZQPtEPAyL9GjTA",
"id": "AUieDaYwCH-aK1B9dvk6ijD2k6khwqIeu_o-r5udRWYei9KQrDQ",
"snippet": {
"videoId": "ZGMg4okOWWM",
"lastUpdated": "2024-01-19T07:15:24.347791Z",
"trackKind": "asr",
"language": "hi",
"name": "",
"audioTrackType": "unknown",
"isCC": false,
"isLarge": false,
"isEasyReader": false,
"isDraft": false,
"isAutoSynced": false,
"status": "serving"
}
}
]
}
""

Comment: Is it one of your video? [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) interesting [Captions: download endpoint](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/download) is only usable by the channel owning the given videos we want the captions of (source: [this StackOverflow comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30653865/downloading-captions-always-returns-a-403#comment49414961_30660549), I verified this fact).

Comment: Please include your code in your question