Has anyone been able to download a YouTube video transcript, using CURL, via oauth2, using the YouTube API without getting a 403 error?
I want to be able to build an Apple Shortcut (app) that uses GET and POST calls to YouTube to download a transcript given a "videoId".  The steps seem to be:

Set up an oauth2 app on the google console (redirect uris, etc)...
HTTP GET to the google oauth endpoint to receive an auth token
Exchange that auth token for an access token
Call the API you need with the access token

And everything works when I call the "captions.list" endpoint but when I try to actually download a transcript, I get a 403 error.  Has anyone gotten this to work?

The error 403 is well-known, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30653865/downloading-captions-always-returns-a-403#comment49414961_30660549. You can either use yt-dlp or the low-level approach described in the Stack Overflow answer 70013529.
